# Esperar que se ejecute archoivo llamado desde shell_exec() php

Tags: php

Hola como puedo hacer para que shell_exec() espere que se termine de ejecutar el archivo que estoy llamando
ejemplo
`$output = shell_exec('python outpuPy.py');`

Comment: La respuesta debería cargarse a $output, que te muestra eso? Y cual es la respuesta deseada?

Comment: si la respuesta deberia cargarse en esa variable $output, el archivo .py es un consumidor de un WS se demora un poco en dar respuesta, pero php no espera que ese archivo traiga la respuesta, coloque un set_time_limit antes pero no funciona, ni con sleep

Comment: Ahhh, tu eres la del otro dia. Copia y pega tu codigo a ver como resulta ser. Cuanto tiempo le has dado, y cuanta demora quieres tener.

Comment: Si te interesa recuperar la salida del comando, quizá deberías usar [**`exec()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php).

Comment: @A.Cedano ya use exec() pero no espera el tiempo tampoco

Comment: @Excorpion no le e dado tiempo, porque nose como darle un tiempo de espera aprox de 2 minutos

Comment: En las *Notas de contribución* del Manual de PHP hay [algunos ejemplos sobre ejeución de comandos en segundo plano](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php#86329) (que podría convenir en procesos largos), por ejemplo, escribiendo la salida en un archivo y leyendo posteriormente en ese archivo.